# what is the shotcut key used to switch between keyword view and expert view in qtp

Tags: qtp

what is the shotcut key used to switch between keyword view and expert view in qtp.

Answer (score 3):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Pageup</kbd> / <kbd>Pagedown</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

You should really try the help some time; it is rather good! For example, searching for `shortcut keyword expert view` and you are 1 click away from the answer to your question. Less haggle then making a stack overflow profile and creating a question if you ask me.

Comment: But anyone who found your answer is at least a `F1`-type and then 1 click away. Why not include the actual answer in your answer?

Comment: Because user red already gave that answer before me. I gave him a upvote for that and would't steal his correct answer in my own. Though, I still stand by the point that the Help function of QTP is underestimated.